# Skip only hostname verification with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to skip hostname verification with httpclient 4.2.1 without changing the trustmanager. I archived this like this:

```
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(a, b);
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().get("https").getSchemeSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

... but setHostnameVerifier method i used is deprecated. How can i achieve the same thing with using not deprecated methods?

Answer (score 5):

DON'T DO THIS!!!

As explained to you at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547114/3081018 already this is a very bad idea and effectively disables all validation, because an attacker then could use any certificate for some other host to mount a man-in-the-middle attack.

It does not get more secure you ask the same question again.

Comment: I thought i will explain it in the previous thread, but because there were many other questions there i thought i will make a new thread with only this one question. The case is that the this is happening in a closed testing environment so security is not an issue. In the real environment there will be a trusted certificate with the correct hostname, but for now i would just want a workaround.

Comment: If security is not an issue than why do you want to verify anything at all? It makes no sense to verify part of the certificate only, i.e. either all or nothing.

Answer (score 5):

As previous people have said you should only do this when you have a very good reason to do so. I also have closed testing environments and I only disable Hostname Verification when it is absolutely needed. The only place it is disabled is in the application running tests never in an application that would be deployed to user facing servers.

This can be accomplished by quickly implementing your own HostnameVerifier.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
HostnameVerifier allowAll = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostName, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
    .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, allowAll))
    .build();
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [SSLConnectionSocketFactory](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html) instead of `SSLSocketFactory` , because `SSLSocketFactory` is depricated

Comment: And if you implement this don't forget to ask yourself why you prefer broken validation to no validation. The effort needed by an attacker to get around this insecurity is practically the same as with no validation.

Comment: What is buildSSLContext()? :)
I dont think this is quite what im looking for. I dont want to trust all certs, i only want to skip hostname verification.

Comment: I'm sure that author has its own reason to do this

Comment: I'm not sure that the author fully understands the problems involved.

Comment: @user1985273 You ask about SSLSocketFactory  - it is depricated (4.3) use SSLConnectionSocketFactory.  look at https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html

Comment: @user1985273  buildSSLContext is a function which inits SSL context, you could you standart  initialization

Comment: @user1985273 Look at good apache example: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java